# Azure App Service doesn't override appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to access a connection string that is specified in Azure App Service configuration

***conn str image***

[image]

but Azure is seem to make no effect on my appsettings.json (configuration)

My appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings":{
    "ConnStr": ""
  },
  "Auth":{
    "AllowedUserNameCharacters":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+"
  },
  "JWT": {
    "ValidIssuer": "http://localhost:5000",
    "ValidAudience": "http://localhost:5000",
    "Secret": ""
  },
  "Email": {
    "SendGridKey": ""
  }
}
```

That's how I access the config in my app:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(configuration);
...
c.UseNpgsql(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr"))
```

But Azure logs still tells me:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

How do I work this out?

The app source code resides here: https://github.com/Rostand-Corp/flitch-backend/tree/develop

I have tried not using .AddEnvironmentVariables()
I have tried giving my initial appsettings.json values

Comment: have you tried putting your ConnStr as a regular app setting instead of a "ConnectionString"? Technically they are not really different, but I'm pretty sure this way it would work.

Comment: Do you mean to access it like configuration[“ConnStr”]? Yes, I did. I have also checked env for my app and noticed, that all the other config strings don’t have any prefixes and ConnStr does, so I think I should maybe access it this way

Comment: Check with this as well.`var connString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:ConnStr");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding `appsettings.json` doesn't mean the changes will be reflected in the deployed `appsettings.json`.

The `appsettings.json` file will not be updated, the changed values can be seen in the `Environment`/`Connection Strings` in `KUDU` Console.

Try to print and check whether you are able to fetch the `Connection String`.

In `appsettings.json` I have set sample string value for `ConnectionString`.

```cs
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnStr": "Local ConnString"
  },
```

- As your connection String Type is `PostgreSQL`.
- I have tried in multiple ways.
  Still unable to fetch from `Azure Connection String`.

```cs
  var ConnStr = myconfig.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:ConnStr");
  var ConnStr1 = myconfig.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings_ConnStr");
  var ConnStr2 = myconfig.GetValue<string>("ConnStr");

  var ConnStr3 = myconfig.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:ConnStr");
  var ConnStr4 = myconfig.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings_ConnStr");
  var ConnStr5 = myconfig.GetConnectionString("ConnStr");
```

Thanks @Silent for the comment.

- I have set the value in the `Application Settings`.

[image]

To make work both in local and Azure, then set the key with name `ConnectionStrings:ConnStr` in Application Settings

- So Iam getting the value only with below code (after setting in `Application Settings`).

```cs
  var ConnStr = myconfig.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:ConnStr");
  var ConnStr5 = myconfig.GetConnectionString("ConnStr");
```

Above code works for both the environments.

***Local Output:***

[image]

***Deployed App OutPut:***

[image]

***My API Controller:***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ConnectionStringAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    { 
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        public readonly IConfiguration myconfig;
        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger,IConfiguration conn)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            myconfig = conn;
        }

            var ConnStr = myconfig.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:ConnStr");
            var ConnStr1 = myconfig.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings_ConnStr");
            var ConnStr2 = myconfig.GetValue<string>("ConnStr");

            var ConnStr3 = myconfig.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:ConnStr");
            var ConnStr4 = myconfig.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings_ConnStr");
            var ConnStr5 = myconfig.GetConnectionString("ConnStr");

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = ConnStr + " GetValue ConnectionStrings:ConnStr",
                TemperatureC = ConnStr1 + " GetValue ConnectionStrings_ConnStr",
                TemperatureF = ConnStr2 + " GetValue ConnStr",

                Summary = ConnStr3 + " GetConnection ConnectionStrings:ConnStr",
                Test = ConnStr4 + " GetConnection ConnectionStrings_ConnStr ",
                Test1 = ConnStr5 + " GetConnection ConnStr"
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the ways to fix this. I had to check the ASP.NET code and default configuration provider isn't configured to recognize POSTGRESQLCONNSTR prefix, but it does recognize AzureSQL, MSSQL and MySql prefixes. So, I have run env command in my SSH and just checked the name of the env variable and in my code I had two ways: 1) get it as env variable, 2) add "POSTGRESQLCONNSTR" prefix to .AddEnvironmentVariables() in configuration builder. I have chosen the first one. Thank you!

Comment: Please refer about [POSTGRESQLCONNSTR__](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/asp-net-sql-connection-string-asp-net-core)  prefix once.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else comes across this thread as I did when trying to resolve the issue.

In my case I am using a PostgreSQL database on Azure and the Connection String I setup in Azure Configuration was also not overriding the connection string specified in appsettings.json.

Changing the Type of the connection string in Azure Configuration from *PostgreSQL* to *Custom* solved the problem.

[image]

Comment: omg, this literally saved my life, like literally. Thanks Tony!

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER, RIGHT HERE